# How can I reply an answer if I don't have enough reputation to comment

Tags: discussion, comments

I asked a question and someone answered, but I want more information.  I don't have enough reputation to comment and say I want more info.  The only thing I see I could do is edit my post and add my response.  But it seems kind if weird to say in the question "Hey you with the first answer, can you be a little clearer?"  What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Although you don't have enough reputation to post comments, if I remember correctly, you should be able to post comments on answers of your own questions... *I might be mistaken though*

Comment: Okay, I guess I can.  That pretty much answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a threshold but it is not that high. You need 50 reputation to leave comments.

I believe it is easier if you first focus on answering questions that do not need comments. Skip the questions that need more information for now and get a bit of reputation first.

50 reputation can be gained with 5 easy answers. You just got to beat others in answering (both in speed and accuracy).

Comment: +1 for "first focus on answering questions that do not need comments". Having said that, anyone who can support the community by editing/formatting 25 questions & answers can gain 50 points like a piece of cake. More the users are involved, the more points are.. :)